# CIWEB1008 error when connecting ICN to ACCE object store

Tags: filenet-p8, ibm-content-navigator, filenet-cpe

I'm having issues trying connecting the ICN to the created object store in ACCE.
When I try to connect I get a CIWEB1008 error.

I installed Filenet 5.2.1 on a clean single windows 2016 server using CPIT without any issue. Also creating a object store based on file share in ACCE went all well. But as mentioned earlier when connecting from the ICN I get a CIWEB1008 error.

I tried checking the SystemOut.log but there is no log entry unless I fill in a false username and password.

Also I tried the stuff mentioned http://ian-wilson.co.uk/archives/455/

How can I get it working?

Comment: did you check SystemErr log if ICN websphere profile?

Comment: Thank you for the help. But in the SystemErr log doesn't give me any error as well after trying a connecting to the filenet server.

It does however give me a log4j errors. Should there normally be an error when I failed to connect?

`[1/8/18 1:00:09:052 PST] 00000094 SystemErr     R log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (filenet_error.api.com.filenet.apiimpl.util.ConfigValueLookup).
[1/8/18 1:00:09:052 PST] 00000094 SystemErr     R log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.`

Comment: this doesn't help much. Can you compare AD settings on ACCE to ICN Websphere profile?

Comment: Is the ObjectStore configured as a repository on the ICN admin desktop?